# How to real-time update range in the x-tick using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a log file that will update every 10 seconds. This is log content at 30th seconds

```
Iteration 0, data = 1.0
Iteration 10, data = 4.0
Iteration 20, data = 5.0
Iteration 30, data = 8.0
```

I will use `matplotlib` in the Python 2.7 to a realtime drawing. It worked well as bellow without minor issue. The issue is the value of x-tick (represents iterations number) does not clear previous range, result in an overlaping displayed range in x-tick ( the same issue appear in y-tick). It means that if I add one more row the log.txt as `Iteration 40, data = 5.0`, then x-tick value will be overlap between old iterations `[0,10,20,30]` and `[0,10,20,30,40]`. I just want to show the newest range `[0,10,20,30,40]`. How could I fix it?

[image]

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot

plt.ion()
while True:
    f = open("./log.txt", 'r')
    iterations = []
    data = []
    for line in f:
        if 'Iteration ' in line and 'data = ' in line:
            arr = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b,', line)
            iterations.append(int(arr[0].strip(',')[0:]))
            data.append(float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1]))
    f.close()

    host = host_subplot(111)  # , axes_class=AA.Axes)
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
    host.set_xlabel("Iterations")
    host.set_ylabel("Loss")
    p1, = host.plot(iterations, data, label="Data")
    plt.pause(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options here. In any case, you need to create the axes outside the loop, otherwise you'll end up with lots of overlaying axes.

1. **Clear the axes**:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import re
   from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot

   plt.ion()
   host = host_subplot(111) 
   plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

   while True:
       f = open("./log.txt", 'r')
       iterations = []
       data = []
       for line in f:
           if 'Iteration ' in line and 'data = ' in line:
               arr = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b,', line)
               iterations.append(int(arr[0].strip(',')[0:]))
               data.append(float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1]))
       f.close()

       host.clear()
       host.set_xlabel("Iterations")
       host.set_ylabel("Loss")
       p1, = host.plot(iterations, data, label="Data")
       plt.draw()
       plt.pause(3)
   ```
2. **Update the data**:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import re
   from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot

   plt.ion()

   host = host_subplot(111)
   plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
   host.set_xlabel("Iterations")
   host.set_ylabel("Loss")
   p1, = host.plot([],[], label="Data")

   while True:
       f = open("./log.txt", 'r')
       iterations = []
       data = []
       for line in f:
           if 'Iteration ' in line and 'data = ' in line:
               arr = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b,', line)
               iterations.append(int(arr[0].strip(',')[0:]))
               data.append(float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1]))
       f.close()
       p1.set_data(iterations, data)
       host.relim()
       host.autoscale_view()
       plt.draw()
       plt.pause(3)
   ```

Comment: How about if I use legend?
 `host.legend(loc=2)   host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())`. How sould I move it to where?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. There is no legend, but if you want to use a legend, there are a lot of questions about legends here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBegingErnest: Could you check the second options. It does not work